# function wp_head() wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Ando en la tarea de optimizar la carga de un sitio **wordpress**, veo que tiene demasiados `plugin` que hace que en la cabecera se haga varios llamados a los `scripts` y `css`, y por lo que vi, ese llamado global lo hace la función `wp_head();` hay alguna forma de llamar solo los `scripts.js` y solo los `estilos.css`? y adicionalmente solo quisiera cargar en el head un solo `script` que es indispensable para la carga.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: podrias quitar el wp_head() y colocar los que necesitas en la plantilla, pero si hay nuevos plugins que necesitan ese método tendras dificultades.

Answer (score 0):

La optimización del sitio en cuestión de tiempos de carga lo puedes resolver con una o varias capas de cache.

Ahora bien para optimizar aún más tus `scripts` podrías utilizar `webpack.js` (o cualquiera similar) para encapsular todos tus **`css's`** y **`js's`** en uno solo minificado y llamar únicamente a esos dos archivos.

La problemática siempre va a estar en que si instalas `plugins`, estos insertarán todo lo que necesitan para funcionar y esto ya es fuera de tu control. Quitar el `wp_head()` no es recomendable ya que estas quitando todo el soporte del `head` de `wp`.